# User can only be linked to one identity for the given provider

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am building an application wherein user can **log in anonymously** and later can choose to **login with Google or facebook**. I've followed the steps mentioned in **[firebase site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth)** and also **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135248/firebase-auth-linking-error-user-can-only-be-linked-to-one-identity-for-the-gi)** but still am getting an error which reads -

> code: "auth/provider-already-linked",
>   message: "User can only be
>   linked to one identity for the given provider."

Below are my **auth.service.ts** contents

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  user: Observable<User>;
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router) {
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState
      .switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`usersData/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
        } else {
          return Observable.of(null)
        }
    });
  }

  anonymousLogin(): Promise<any>{
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously();
  }

  get authState(): Observable<User>{
    return this.afAuth.authState.map(data => {
      return data;
    });
  }

  get currentUser(): boolean {
    return this.user !== null;
  }

  getCurrentUser(): User{
    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
  }

  googleLogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
  }

  facebookLogin(){
    const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    provider.setCustomParameters({
      'display': 'popup'
    });
    return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
  }

  private oAuthLogin(provider) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((response) => {
        if(this.getCurrentUser() !== null){
          let cred = null;
          if(response.credential.providerId === 'google.com'){
            cred = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
                   .credential(response.credential.idToken);
          }else if(response.credential.providerId === 'facebook.com'){
            cred = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
                   .credential(response.credential.authToken);
          }
          firebase.auth().currentUser
          .linkWithCredential(cred).then(function(user) {
            console.log("Anonymous account successfully upgraded", user);
          }, function(error) {
            console.log("Error upgrading anonymous account", error);
          });
        }
        this.updateUserData(response.user)
      });
  }

  private updateUserData(user) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`usersData/${user.uid}`);
    const data: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      isAnonymous: user.isAnonymous,
      roles: {
        customer: true
      }
    };
    return userRef.set(data, {merge: true});
  }
  signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {

    });
  }
}
```

As suggested in other posts referred I've used `linkWithCredential` method by passing required `idToken/accessToken` but it is failing to link the accounts on both providers and hence end up creating multiple accounts under **Authentication-> Users**.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction or am I missing anything here?

Comment: Are you aware of this: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web?

Comment: @Tilo.. Well haven't knew about this.. Thanks for introducing. I'll try to implement this. Still am curious to know why the above issue is occuring?

Comment: Have you enabled the option to allow [users to sign in with multiple auth providers](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400716)?  It's configured in the console under **Sign-in methods**

Comment: @JasonBerryman I've **`Prevent creation of multiple accounts with the same email address`** option set under that. This isn't gonna work like this?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, then you should allow users to use multiple sign-n methods.  To clarify, are you wanting to allow users to use multiple auth providers and have a single Firebase Auth uid?

Comment: @JasonBerryman Not exactly.. For example, if the user first registers with Google and then tries to register with Facebook am giving proper error message saying account already exists with other provider.. But when he is registered anonymously then I want to link it with the currently chosen sign in method (Facebook/Google).. I hope I have cleared it.. please let me know if anything else has to be clarified..

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting `auth/provider-already-linked` error code, it means you have already linked the provider to that user. You can only link a provider once. You can't have multiple Facebook accounts to the same user. Only once. If you want to remove that account, you have to unlink it: `firebase.auth().currentUser.unlink(firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)`.
You can then link a new Facebook credential to that user.

Comment: I got to try this. Do I need to also set option to have multiple accounts? Or only per account will be sufficient?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't have multiple entries of the same provider on a user. Firebase Auth enforces that. If you are referring to "multiple accounts per email", that is a different thing. It means for a facebook account, you would have one user and a Google account of the same email, a different user.

Comment: No.. I was confused with below answer. But with the approach specified in the post, when should I be doing `unlink` functionality?

Comment: It's up to you. You don't really need to. In case you are testing, you may need to unlink the provider and try again.

Comment: I think this can happen in the following scenario: the user is registered with `u1@email.com` to the provider, then logs in and that gets linked. Then sometimes later the user changes his primary email to `u2@email.com` with that provider. Then next time the user tries to login the standard link procedure shenanigan starts again, but the midst of it on the provider's side it is uncovered that this is the same user. This whole thing ends up with the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert an anonymous authenticated user to a paermanent account.

View the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account) for more details.  I believe that for this to work, you'll have to modify your Auth settings to allow users to login in from multiple accounts.

Comment: I've followed the same docs with my current approach. I've also set option to have multiple accounts. But still no luck.

Comment: I would suggest that you add some console.log points at each stage, which include the name of the function and the data you are processing, to see where it's going wrong.